# Excel - macro to important data from several workbooks based on cell name

Tags: excel, vlookup, commandbutton, vba

I've been trying to make the below code work, and it did yesterday evening, but somehow this morning upon opening Excel it stopped functioning. Essentially, I'm using a vlookup macro to important data from various workbooks, and the workbook names depend on the respective "title" of that row. First, I check with an if statement whether the file actually exists; if it doesn't, I want to highlight the title cell red, and move onto the next row to carry out the same check. If the file does exist, I want to populate the row with the appropriate data and highlight the title cell with white colour.

Below my code - I'd really appreciate if you could take a look and help me out!

```
Public Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo NextStep
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True

NextStep:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wsi As Worksheet
    Dim wse As Worksheet
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set wsi = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Income")
    Set wse = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expense")

    j = 3

    For i = 1 To 46

        If FileFolderExists(wsi.Cells(5, i + 2).Value & ".xlsx") Then
            wsi.Range(wsi.Cells(6, j), wsi.Cells(51, j)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(index($B$6:$AV$51,row()-5,1),'[" & wsi.Cells(5, i + 2).Value & ".xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$E$70,4,FALSE)"
            Sheets("Mark-Up Table").Cells(i + 5, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Sheets("Mark-Up Table").Cells(5, i + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Else
            Sheets("Mark-Up Table").Cells(i + 5, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Sheets("Mark-Up Table").Cells(5, i + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If

        If FileFolderExists(wse.Cells(5, i + 2).Value & ".xlsx") Then
            wse.Range(wse.Cells(6, j), wse.Cells(51, j)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(index($B$6:$AV$51,row()-5,1),'[" & wse.Cells(5, i + 2).Value & ".xlsx]Sheet2'!$A$1:$E$70,5,FALSE)"

        Else
            'do nothing
        End If

        j = j + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: what error number you have and where?

Comment: thanks for your reply KazJaw. It doesn't yield en error number, it just doesn't do what it's supposed to. I suspect the problem is with the public function at the top before the private sub commences. I want the first if statement in the sub to check "ok does this file exist?" which is done via the public function. If it is, then proceed. If not, head to the next else if statement below.

Comment: try to step-debug your code. Add `Stop` at the beginning of `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` procedure and than debug it with F8 key. Check the variables where you expect essential point of your subroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue. For people who might be facing similar problems, please see below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim strPath As String

    Dim wsi As Worksheet
    Dim wse As Worksheet

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set wsi = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Income")
    Set wse = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expense")

    strPath = Sheets("Mark-Up Table").Range("H3").Value

    j = 3

    For i = 1 To 46

        If Dir(strPath & wsi.Cells(i + 5, 2).Value & ".xlsx") = vbNullString Then
            Sheets("Mark-Up Table").Cells(i + 5, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Sheets("Mark-Up Table").Cells(5, i + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            wsi.Range(wsi.Cells(3 + j, 3), wsi.Cells(3 + j, 48)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(index($C$5:$AV$51,1,column()-2),'[" & wsi.Cells(i + 5, 2).Value & ".xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$E$70,4,FALSE)"
            Sheets("Mark-Up Table").Cells(i + 5, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Sheets("Mark-Up Table").Cells(5, i + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If

        If Dir(strPath & wse.Cells(5, i + 2).Value & ".xlsx") = vbNullString Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            wse.Range(wse.Cells(6, j), wse.Cells(51, j)).Formula = "=abs(VLOOKUP(index($B$6:$AV$51,row()-5,1),'[" & wse.Cells(5, i + 2).Value & ".xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$E$70,5,FALSE))"
        End If

        j = j + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```